# Cutting The Sticks

Tags: c, array, programming-challenge

**Problem Statement**

This is a [challenge from HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101feb14/challenges/cut-the-sticks):

> You are given N sticks, where each stick has the length of a positive
>   integer. A cut operation is performed on the sticks such that all of
>   them are reduced by the length of the smallest stick.
>
> Suppose we have six sticks of the following lengths:
>
> ```
> 5 4 4 2 2 8
> ```
>
> Then, in one cut operation we make a cut of length 2 from each of the
>   six sticks. For the next cut operation four sticks are left (of
>   non-zero length), whose lengths are the following:
>
> ```
> 3 2 2 6
> ```
>
> The above step is repeated until no sticks are left.
>
> Given the length of N sticks, print the number of sticks that are cut
>   in subsequent cut operations.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains a single integer \$N\$.  The next line contains \$N\$
>   integers: \$a_0, a_1,\ldots, a_{N-1}\$ separated by space, where \$a_i\$ represents the
>   length of \$i^{th}\$ stick.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> For each operation, print the number of sticks that are cut in
>   separate line.
>
> Constraints: \$1 ≤ N ≤ 1000\$ and \$1 ≤ a_i ≤ 1000\$
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 6
> 5 4 4 2 2 8
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 6
> 4
> 2
> 1
> ```

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

      int n;
      scanf("%d",&n);
      int a[n-1];
      for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
      {
          int stick;
          scanf("%d",&stick);
          a[i]=stick;
      } 
       int f=0;
      do
      {
          int count=0,small=99;
          f=0;
          for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
          {
              if(a[i]>0&&a[i]<small)
                  small=a[i];
          }   
          for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
          {
              if(a[i]!=0)
              {
                  a[i]=a[i]-small;
                  ++count;
                  f=1;
              }    
          }
          if(count)
         printf("%d\n",count);
      }while(f==1);    

    return 0;
}
```

How can I improve the above code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Variable names

You seem to enjoy short variable names such as `a`, `n`, `f`. These names don't really explain much, especially not the `f`. `a` can be named `array` or `data` (or even better: `sticks`), and `n` can be named `length` or similar.

#### Potential bug

The constraint is `1 ≤ ai ≤ 1000` but you initialize `small` to 99, which means that if the input is something like:

```
4
123 123 140 147
```

Your code won't work correctly.

#### Code Style

It is a good practice to use a bit more spacing than you are using, ittendstohelpswithreadability.

It is also recommended to always use braces, even on one-line statements. Bugs have happened before because of this, only a matter of time before bugs happen again.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    if (a[i] > 0 && a[i] < small)
    {
        small = a[i];
    }
}
```

On this line, you can use `-=` operator:

```
a[i]=a[i]-small;
```

Has same effect as:

```
a[i] -= small;
```

#### Approach

You are looping through the array multiple times and cutting until there are no more elements to cut. This makes your code have worst-case complexity \$O(n^2)\$ (if all elements would be unique, you would loop \$n\$ times over \$n\$ elements, so \$n^2\$). It is possible to reduce this to \$O(n * log(n))\$ by sorting the array first, and then looping through it.

For example:

```
6
5 4 4 2 2 8
```

If we start by sorting this:

```
6
2 2 4 4 5 8
```

And then loop through it:

- We encounter a `2`, we know this is the smallest and that the number of elements in the array is 6 so we know we will have to cut 6 sticks. No need to do the actual cutting. **Output 6**
- We encounter another 2 but this is the same as the previous element so no need to do anything.
- We encounter a 4. This is not equal to 2. We are currently at index 2 so we know that there are \$6 - 2 = 4\$ elements left in the array. Those elements needs to be cut. **Output 4**
- Shortly after we encounter the value 5, with only 2 elements left to loop through. So cutting 2 elements. **Output 2**
- We encounter the 8, only one element left to cut. **Output 1**